# How to pick date and time from user easily in angular?

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

How to pick date and time input from the user? I need to save it in firestore timestamp property using Angular. Please give me a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Angular Date Time Picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime) package of npm to get the date and time from the input.

Sample Code

1) module.ts

```
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        OwlDateTimeModule,
        OwlNativeDateTimeModule
    ],
})
```

2) component.html

```
<input type="text" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" [owlDateTime]="dt1"
    formControlName="installDate" id="installDate" autocomplete="off"
    (ngModelChange)="onInstallDateChange()" class="form-control" 
    [max]="currentDate" />
<owl-date-time #dt1 pickerType="calendar"></owl-date-time>
```

3) component.ts

```
onInstallDateChange() {
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: I think it's some other package that is affecting this.

Comment: It's on change event. When you select date-time from date picker, the event will fire.

Answer (score -1):

ERROR in ../../node_modules/ng-pick-datetime/date-time/date-time-picker.component.d.ts:2:62 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/overlay'.

2 import { BlockScrollStrategy, Overlay, ScrollStrategy } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
                                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../node_modules/ng-pick-datetime/dialog/dialog-config.class.d.ts:2:32 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/overlay'.

2 import { ScrollStrategy } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../node_modules/ng-pick-datetime/dialog/dialog-container.component.d.ts:3:34 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'.

3 import { FocusTrapFactory } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../node_modules/ng-pick-datetime/dialog/dialog-container.component.d.ts:4:84 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/portal'.

4 import { BasePortalOutlet, CdkPortalOutlet, ComponentPortal, TemplatePortal } from '@angular/cdk/portal';
                                                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../node_modules/ng-pick-datetime/dialog/dialog-ref.class.d.ts:2:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/overlay'.

2 import { OverlayRef } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../node_modules/ng-pick-datetime/dialog/dialog.service.d.ts:6:59 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/overlay'.

6 import { Overlay, OverlayContainer, ScrollStrategy } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../node_modules/ng-pick-datetime/dialog/dialog.service.d.ts:7:31 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/portal'.

7 import { ComponentType } from '@angular/cdk/portal';
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.